# matlab figure event listener does not trigger when widow resized

Tags: matlab, graphics, event-listener

**Version**: Matlab R2014b

**XY problem disclaimer**: my objective is to make MATLAB format ticks in my graphic with a certain custom function that takes as argument the tick position and outputs a string. Default tick placement is ok but I want to control the labels. Failure to execute the callback function as ticks change results in mislabelled ticks.

The MWE below shows dummy versions of the callback; the real callback sets tick labels to the output of

```
tick_formatter = @(tv)([sprintf('%1.2f',tv/10^N) 'e' num2str(N)])
```

(where tv is the tick value in X units). (This is a crude replacement for `ax.XAxis.Exponent` of versions R2015b and following, see https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/275054-change-multiple-exponent-on-x-axis)

**The actual problem**:

I want to be able to do "something" (in my case recompute tick labels) every time ticks change (i.e. their number or their y-value changes). To do so I looked at `addlistener` but I cannot manage to make it work as I wish.

Ideally, I would put a listener on the `XTick` property but it does not seem to work correctly. When `XTickMode` is on `auto`, zooming in and out (programatically by `xlim()` or by hand) or resizing the graphic window will cause change in the number / position of ticks, and consequently change the value returned by `get(ax,'XTick')`, but it will not trigger such an event listener.

For zooming in/out, a workaround is to listen to `XLim` instead, which does trigger events; but I found no such workaround for figure window resizing (at least using listeners at the axes object level).

Any suggestions welcome.

**MWE**:

```
% generate figure
x = 0:100;
y = x.^2;
figure(1)
clf() % ensure we cleared out previous tests
plot(x,y)
ax = gca();

% This event listener does nothing as you zoom in/out or resize the graphic
% window, even though XTick does change; it will only respond to explicit
% commands e.g. set(ax, 'XTick', ...). 
listen_to_XTick = addlistener(ax, 'XTick', 'PostSet',@(src,evn) disp('XTick changed'));

% This event listener responds to zooming in/out, but not to window
% resizing
listen_to_XLim = addlistener(ax, 'XLim', 'PostSet',@(src,evn) disp('XLim changed'));

% Play a bit with the figure, zoom in/out, resize the graphics window etc.
% -> only listen_to_XLim ever gets triggered, never listen_to_XTick

% Other properties that do not seem to ever trigger as window is resized:
% 'XTick', 'XTickLabel', 'Position'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to change your tick labels when your figure window is resized, you could make use of the `SizeChangedFcn` callback of the [figure](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html) window itself. Try:

```
f = figure('SizeChangedFcn',@(src,evn) disp('Window resized'))
```

Comment: Accepting because it solves my problem, but I will note it is not a "proper" solution: (1) as already described, this is playing around the fact that there is apparently no proper listener for XTick, so we listen to everything that can change XTick instead; (2) it is linked to the figure object, not the the axes, which can be an issue in some circumstances (if you change the axes position within the figure, it will not callback; if the callback contains calls to axes object properties, bugs will happen if you delete the axes but not the figure).

Comment: Glad it helped. If you would like to cover the other cases aswell, you could simply trigger the same callback with another listener such as the one you already described (`addlistener(ax, 'XLim', 'PostSet',@(src,evn) disp('XLim changed')`).