# Labeling plots such that label is aligned with the ylabel outside the axes

Tags: matlab, plot, label, alignment, subplot

Please see the following code which creates a 2 by 2 subplot with some plots:

```
x = linspace(0,2*pi);
y = sin(x);
hfig = figure('Position',[1317 474 760 729]);
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(x,y)
ylabel('plot1');
subplot(2,2,2)
plot(x,y.^2)
ylabel('plot2');
subplot(2,2,3)
plot(x,y.^3)
ylabel('plot3');
subplot(2,2,4)
plot(x,abs(y))
ylabel('plot4');
```

in each one, I have added labels by hand in Tools: Edit plot (a) (b) (c) (d) producing this figure:

[image: image 1]

The problem is, if I resize the plot they are no longer aligned with the ylabel text:

[image: image 2]

Is there a way to add these labels programmatically and have them automatically align to the ylabel text? I am surprised MATLAB does not have something like this built in already.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not something that is easy to do without attaching a listener to the figure resize event (see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51156590/3372061)), and doing some computations related to aspect ratios.

It's not entirely clear what sort of objects your labels are (`text` or `annotation`), so I'll just show how to do this programmatically using the [`text`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) command, which creates labels in **axes coordinates** (as opposed to *figure* coordinates). This doesn't solve the problem entirely, but it looks better, possibly to an acceptable degree:

```matlab
function q56624258
x = linspace(0,2*pi);
y = sin(x);
hF = figure('Position',[-1500 174 760 729]);

%% Create plots
[hAx,hYL] = deal(gobjects(4,1)); 
for ind1 = 1:3
  hAx(ind1) = subplot(2,2,ind1, 'Parent' , hF);
  plot(hAx(ind1), x,y.^ind1);
  hYL(ind1) = ylabel("plot" + ind1);
end

hAx(4) = subplot(2,2,4);
plot(hAx(4), x,abs(y));
hYL(4) = ylabel('plot4');

%% Add texts (in data coordinates; x-position is copied from the y-label)
for ind1 = 1:4
  text(hAx(ind1), hYL(ind1).Position(1), 1.1, ['(' char('a'+ind1-1) ')'], ...
    'HorizontalAlignment', 'center');
end
```

[image]

Note several modifications to your code:

- The handles returned by some functions that create graphical elements are now stored (mainly: `hAx`, `hYL`).
- All functions that create graphical elements (`subplot`, `plot`, `ylabel`) now have the target (i.e. parent or container) specified.
- I changed the `'Position'` of the figure so that it works in my setup (you might want to change it back).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the thorough answer. Actually, I think adding the ability to resize is overkill for me at this stage (but I appreciate the know how!). After fixing the plot size, your idea of using the handle to the ylabel as the position works perfectly. Infact, if I use, `text(hax,hylab.Position(1),max(ylim),'(a)','HorizontalAlignment','right');` it will automatcially put the text right in the perfect place. Thanks!

Comment: Strangly enough, I discovered that when running my above code in a script, sometimes the alignments are a little off. This can be fixed by simply adding `pause(0.5)` before the `text` command... No idea why, maybe MATLAB hasn't sorted out its handles in the right order sometimes?

Comment: @Steve this is because the positions are "not final" until the figure is actually drawn. `pause` simply gives MATLAB an opportunity to draw the figure and update the positions and sizes of graphical elements. The more correct way is to use `drawnow` instead of `pause`, although they achieve the same result in your case.